# How to roughly transform cpp code structure to python

Tags: python, c++, structure, doxygen

Given a project written in C++ with lots of classes (more than a hundred), how to make a rough reimplementation of the code structure?

---

**Edit: as more details are required.**

For a project that implements a specific UML Class diagram, I would like to have the same class diagram info generated into Python

Example Source:

```
 my_app
   - models  
     - Company.py (company class)
     - Employee.cpp (employee class)
     - Laptop.cpp (laptop class)
     - Office.cpp (office class)
   - common
     - utils.cpp (operations and extras classes)
   ...
```

Example Output after extraction:

```
- Company.py
- Employee.py
- Laptop.py
- Office.py
- Operations.py
- Extras.py
```

Note: As we extract the Class diagram info, generated classes shall contain only the attributes and methods not the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the code with [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and use xml as the output format.
Then use the xml files as input for [Langform](https://github.com/Walid-Shouman/langform).

Comment: What is your affiliation to Langform?

Comment: I created it to solve this question